# Sprite kit - naming repeated objects

Tags: ios, xcode5, sprite-kit

Using apple spritekit, how can I uniquely identify nodes if, say 20 nodes, they have same art work and are to be placed randomly on the screen? Is there a faster way like in cocos2d there is a"tag" function to identify?

Comment: Each node has a "name" property. You can use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not the most proficient with sprites, but is this something you're looking for?

Save:

```
NSArray * nodesArray; // some array of nodes.
for (int x = 0; x < nodesArray.count; x++) {
    SKNode * node = nodesArray[x];
    node.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", x];
}
```

Retrieve:

```
int nodeToRetrieveTag = 2; // or whatever
SKNode* nodeToRetrieve = [self.scene childNodeWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", nodeToRetrieveTag]];
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me null error. May be I'll paste some code and Can have a look over it.

Comment: Got it working finally. I didn't use the array method but I did use stringwithformat method to resolve the issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm usually using the property name:

```
SKNode *myNode = [[SKNode alloc]init];
myNode.name = @"uniqueName";
[self addChild:myNode];
```

In the SKScene, to recovery the node you can do:

```
[self childNodeWithName:@"uniqueName"];  // self is SKScene
```

If for some reason you don't want to use name, you can always subclass one SKNode and add your personal unique identifier:

```
MySpriteNode.h

@interface MySpriteNode : SKSpriteNode

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *personalIdentifier;

@end
```

and
    MySpriteNode.m

```
#import "MySpriteNode.h"

@implementation MySpriteNode

@end
```

with this second option you can:

```
for (MySpriteNode *sprite in [self children]) personalIdentifier
    {
        if ([sprite.personalIdentifier isEqualToString:@"something"])
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**

Try to follow these tutorials, I really think they are great. I learned a lot with them:

- [An iOS 7 Sprite Kit Game Tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Sprite_Kit_Game_Tutorial)
- [Sprite Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW3)
- [Sprite Kit Tutorial for Beginners](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I am still confused if, let's say, I have 20 platforms to be placed at random, Name property will only enable me to identify a particular sprite, so I'll have to define the same sprite 20 times. What I am looking for is a shortcut method by using for loop? I hope I am writing something that makes sense... let me know if I am missing something

Comment: you can use [self children] for loop all the node childrens in the Scene.

Comment: I tried this too but I guess I am missing something in my code.

Comment: Gabriel, thank you for your help. I admit that Logan's answer did help me in my programming a bit. But I am in the soup again. The problem is, my code uses intersectsWithNode method. And when the platform runs off the screen it is suppose to "remove from parent" but this not happening. My program is crashing during detecting the node interference. And it's driving me nuts as my game is almost ready. I was having a very good result when I was defining each platform individually as a SKSPRITENODE. Can you help?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with Sprite Kit too and I never used intersectsWithNode

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName%3ausingBlock%3a) method?

Comment: I tried to see the documentation but I am bit confused. Do you have some reference where I can understand how it works?

Comment: @Ashwin, how it works? From docs: This method enumerates the child array in order, searching for nodes whose name matches the search parameter. The block is called once for each node that matches the name parameter.

How to check: create an SKNode node, add 10-20 empty SKSpriteNodes with property name set to "sprite", initialize userData property and for each newly created sprite set some key like "spriteId" = @(index).

After that you can use enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock: method on SKNode to enumerate all sprites with name you need.